# Unable to map TFS projects to network drive in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm having trouble mapping my TFS projects to a network drive in Visual Studio 2013. I am on an instance of Windows 8.1 in Parallels Desktop 9 for OSX. I keep my various dev files on my OSX file system, not on the VM image. This was not a problem for me using Visual Studio 2012 (see screen shot below), however with Visual Studio 2013 I do not see my Z drive as being available to me. What's changed with 2013? Is there something I can do to get 2013 to work the same way 2012 did for this purpose?

Edit: Also, if I attempt to just enter the correct path in manually, it accepts it but then I get a variety of "could not find part of the path..." errors. Third screenshot shows this.

Edit: Ok, I can not even open projects in VS2013 that are on a network drive. The Open File Dialog that is presenting for opening a project does not show my network paths available, and once again when I enter them manually I get an error. Has Microsoft just completely killed this in 2013?

**Visual Studio 2012 mapping:**
[image: VS2012]

**Visual Studio 2013 mapping:**
[image: VS2013]

**Manually entered path errors:**
[image: Path Errors]

**Open Project Errors**
[image: Open file error]

Comment: Can't you manually type the network drive path (i.e: `Z:`) and then select Browse to navigate to the destination folder? I don't have VS here so I cannot test it.

Comment: Unfortunately I get errors when I do that. I will update the op to reflect this fact.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce either of these situations.  I can map (and get) a TFS project on a network drive.  Likewise, I can open a project from a network drive.  The drive is mapped to Z:\ on my machine as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. No one on my MSDN thread for the issue has been able to reproduce it either. I have attempted to reinstall VS with no luck. I can only conclude that it must be tied to the fact that it's on a VM, although I can't see why that wouldn't affect VS2012 in the same way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience this happens when visual studio is ran as an administrator. The drives are mapped for the logged in user but not for the admin user that is running visual studio. You should be able to verify this by looking at the processes in Windows Task Manager and checking which user is running visual studio.

Comment: The other poster is correct, this was a brilliant catch. I'm only sorry I didn't mark it as the answer sooner since I stopped paying attention to the issue.

Comment: Just ran into this as well, I ended up mapping them from the open file dialog within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

@jwarner is correct that it's because you're running as an admin; this is still true for Visual Studio 2017.  If you want to map a drive to that location so this will work, create a BAT file with the following code:

```
net use x: \\server\share
```

Then run that file with Administrator Privileges, and restart Visual Studio.  You will then have access to that drive.  If you want the drive to still be there after you restart, add `/persistent:yes` to that line in the BAT file.